# Overriding MIME Type in PHP

Tags: php, image, mime-types

My site is requesting a remote image which is being transferred with the wrong MIME type. I was wondering how might I override it in PHP to tell it that it's an image? I can't use header('Content-Type') because the image is being used in a HTML document.

http://manga.justcarl.co.uk/N/Naruto/494/1 - one of the pages attempting to request an image... the image looks broken because it's trying to output it as html

Comment: Obviously the author/hoster of those images does not like remote embedding of his works. So he employed some server-side restrictions (e.g. Referer check). So, stop doing it.

Comment: I initially thought it was Referer check but it isn't :P and this site doesn't really get used by anybody other than me (mobile phone alternative), just some fun more than anything and something for the portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at possibly the server configuration (or maybe a .htaccess file?) in this case. You won't be able to make a solution for this in PHP unless you can change the img src attribute.

Check [this direct link to the image](http://img-a.onemanga.com/mangas/00000004/000315252/01.jpg), it says 403 forbidden for me. Is it different for you?

Comment: Really? Forbidden? No, they've all been loading fine with direct links... I get a forbidden header if I request the image in my page though... one of the reasons I'm so confused :/

I came across .htaccess ForceType, but it isn't working so I'm assuming it's just for local files. How do you mean change the img src attribute? It has a .jpg tag on the end if that's what you mean? :P

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. When I said change the img src attribute, I meant you would have to point the img src to a .php script that loads the image if you wanted to make a solution for this issue in PHP (and while that is entirely doable and could be a good workaround, it is probably not a good long term solution). Sorry I am not familiar with nginx, but I would check out the nginx configuration and see if there is a referrer check for images or something similar that would cause a 403.

Comment: Ahhh, god I came across php images, that should have clicked :P good advice, will look into it, cheers :)

Comment: Your suggestion for php image worked ^^ though it's more work for the server and no browser caching, but definitely a good temporary solution :) hehe